# Change bibtex to biblatex

Tags: biblatex, bibtex, bibliographies

I'm writing my thesis with the University template. However, the template seems to only support **bibtex** but I really want to use commands like `\citet` and `\citep` in **biblatex**. Could anybody tell me how to make changes to the .cls file? Thanks so much!

The citation seems to be controlled by these commands in `thesis.cls` file:

```
\newif\ifrawbibliography \rawbibliographyfalse
\def\thebibliography#1{%
 \ifrawbibliography
 \else
  \newpage
  \thispagestyle{empty}%
  \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{REFERENCES}%
% Switch singlespace to after the heading gets printed.
  \mainheading{REFERENCES}%
  \par\removelastskip\singlespace\par\removelastskip% GBG Oct 1993
  \fixmainheadingSKIP
 \fi
  \list{[\arabic{enumi}]}%
  {\settowidth\labelwidth{[#1]}\leftmargin%
     \labelwidth\advance\leftmargin\labelsep\usecounter{enumi}}%
  \def\newblock{\hskip .11em plus .33em minus -.07em}%
  \sloppy\clubpenalty4000\widowpenalty4000%
  \sfcode`\.=1000\relax
}
\let\endthebibliography=\endlist% why not \endsinglespace?
```

Comment: Roughly you would have to delete everything in the `.cls` file that has to do with bibliographies and then load `biblatex` instead. Then you need to make sure that things look like before.

Comment: Thanks. So you mean I cannot modify the previous commands to control the margin or space?

Comment: You can absolutely do that, but you will probably not be able to use the exact same commands, so you cannot just copy the code from your snipped above, you will have to do some manual work.

Comment: You can control the spacing/margins using the `\defbibenvironment{bibliography}` command. You can look at page 193 of the biblatex manual to see how it works.  For using `\citet`, `\citep` and similar you have to use the biblatex  `natbib` option.

Comment: If you solved your problem yourself, you might want to write and post an answer yourself.

Answer (score 1):

I think I have to delete those bibtex commands and as @Guido suggested I "can control the spacing/margins using the \defbibenvironment{bibliography} command. You can look at page 193 of the biblatex manual to see how it works. For using \citet, \citep and similar you have to use the biblatex natbib option." Thanks!